# Will the fallback flash player succeed at playing ogg vorbis?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I use the `MediaElement.js` plugin for WordPress to play audio.

I would really prefer not having to upload one mp3 file for each ogg vorbis file on the server.

Unfortunately, I am not in a position to test all browsers, so my question is the following:

If I feed an ogg vorbis file to the mp3 parameter, will the fallback Flash player succeed at playing that ogg vorbis file? In WordPress shortcode, this is what I mean:

```
[audio mp3="http://mysite.com/mymedia.ogg" ogg="http://mysite.com/mymedia.ogg"]
```

UPDATE: I ended up uploading one mp3 for each ogg vorbis on the server because the above clearly does not work.

Maybe using something like this:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Libraries

or

http://barelyfocused.net/blog/2008/10/03/flash-vorbis-player/

...would make it possible, in the next version of MediaElement.js, to avoid duplication?